# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Sending SES email

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ses

I'm trying to build a pw recovery solution and I added SES code within the app.post method, but I keep getting `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. The error is being triggered in.

```
ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
         if(err) {
      res.send(err);
         }
```

I added the params code before the User.findOne thinking that would work, but I'm guessing it's talking headers before reaching Api endpoint. Which in that case would not make this possible unless I'm mistaken. How can I get the AWS SES code to play nicely in the app.post?

```
   app.post("/api/users/passwordreset", function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body.email);
let emailValue = req.body.email;

  if (req.body.email !== undefined) {

    // TODO: Using email, find user from your database.


    var ses_mail = "From: 'Auction Site' <" + emailValue+ ">\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " +emailValue + "\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: Password Reset Request\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Click here to reset password." + "\n\n" + 'http://localhost:3000/resetpassword';


    var params = {
      RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer.from(ses_mail) },
      Destinations: [emailValue ],
      Source: "'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + emailValue + ">'"

  };



    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if(user){
        console.log("fetchedUser");
        console.log(user);
        var payload = {
          id: user.id, // User ID from database
          email: user.email
        };

         var secret = user.password + "-" + user.creationDate;
         var token = jwt.sign(payload, secret);
         console.log("payload");
         console.log(token);

         ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
          if(err) {

              res.send(err);
          }
          else {
              res.send(data);
          }
      });

        res.send(
          '<a href="/resetpassword/' +
            payload.id +
            "/" +
            token +
            '">Reset password</a>'
        );

    }
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }


    });

    // TODO: Make this a one-time-use token by using the user's
    // current password hash from the database, and combine it
    // with the user's created date to make a very unique secret key!
    // For example:
    // var secret = user.password + ‘-' + user.created.getTime();

    // TODO: Send email containing link to reset password.
    // In our case, will just return a link to click.
  } else {
    res.send("Email address is missing.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using `res.send` multiple times. Make everything promise , it will work nicely

Comment: I sorted it out. Thanks!